# Why does my commandline within PyCharm not recognize bash commands?

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, kde-plasma, manjaro

I am trying to copy something to my clipboard for a project in Python. I cannot use modules to copy to my clipboard because of a bug with KDE Plasma. Instead of trying to fix that problem, I decided I would work around it with:

```
os.system('echo text | xclip -sel clip')
```

The error I get in return, is

```
sh: xclip: command not found
```

Xclip is installed and works in my own commandline just fine, but with the terminal within Pycharm. The command `sudo` is not recognized. I do not understand why these are not being recognized, and what I must do to be able to access something like xclip from the built-in terminal.

---

Within my functional drop-down:

```
$PATH
bash: /home/danielh/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin: No such file or directory
```

Within my dysfunctional built-in terminal:

```
echo $PATH
/home/danielh/PycharmProjects/DetermineDistances/venv/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin
```

sudo pacman is not recognized either, why am I missing these commands?

---

```
[danielh@Pomegranate DetermineDistances]$ which pacman
which: no pacman in (/app/bin:/usr/bin)
[danielh@Pomegranate DetermineDistances]$ which xclip
which: no xclip in (/app/bin:/usr/bin)
```

I have put `clipboard.sh` in the project directory, but even when it is run, xclip is not found. However, if I run it from my own terminal, it works just fine:

`subprocess.call('./clipboard.sh') ./clipboard.sh: line 2: xclip: command not found`

`[danielh@Pomegranate DetermineDistances]$ ./clipboard.sh` works just fine
`[danielh@Pomegranate DetermineDistances]$ which xclip /usr/bin/xclip` also works

---

@CrazyCoder's solution doesn't seem to have any effect.
`[danielh@Pomegranate bin]$ sudo /var/lib/flatpak/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/current/active/export/bin/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community`  
PyCharm opens up, yet I am still unable to access `pacman` or `xclip`

---

```
(venv) [danielh@Pomegranate DetermineDistances]$ strace -e stat which xclip
strace: test_ptrace_get_syscall_info: PTRACE_TRACEME: Operation not permitted
strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Operation not permitted
strace: PTRACE_SETOPTIONS: Operation not permitted
strace: detach: waitpid(157): No child processes
strace: Process 157 detached
```

Comment: sounds like an issue with PATH variable, is suggest you run 
`os.system('echo $PATH')` and report the result
@Straw, xclip is not a bash builtin, but a binary

Comment: what is the result of `which pacman` and `which xclip`?

Comment: that's weird. what about `strace -e stat which xclip`?

Comment: `sudo strace -e stat which xclip`

Comment: sudo is not found, so I can't do that in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by uninstalling the Flatpak repository installation of PyCharmCE and reinstalling PycharmCE 2020.1.3 using the Snap repository.

```
[danielh@Pomegranate PycharmProjects]$ whereis xclip
xclip: /usr/bin/xclip /usr/share/man/man1/xclip.1.gz
[danielh@Pomegranate PycharmProjects]$ whereis sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /etc/sudo.conf /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Digged a bit deeper, after I saw that you were using a Flatpak installation. Flatpak has its own sandboxing, so this was actually causing the issue.

So, it looks like the Flatpak creates its own `/usr/bin` which totally unrelated to the "host" `/usr/bin`. The real `/usr/bin` is mounted under `/var/run/host/usr/bin` (`/usr`, `/dev` all under `/var/run/host` in general).

So, that's where `xclip` is located. So, if you want to run `xclip` you must first add it to the path:

```
os.environ["PATH"] = "/var/run/host:" + os.environ["PATH"]
```

However, this is not enough since `xclip` also depends on a shared library, called
`LibXmu`, as evident when running the command with this modification:

```
/var/run/host/usr/bin/xclip: error while loading shared libraries: libXmu.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But since, once agian Flatpak does not have the real `/usr/lib` under its `/usr/lib` path, we must provide another environment variable for shared library lookup under `/var/run/host/usr/lib`

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] =  "/var/run/host/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

So, this code should now work:

```
import os
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] =  "/var/run/host/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
os.environ["PATH"] = "/var/run/host/usr/bin:" + os.environ["PATH"]
os.system('echo text | xclip -sel clip')
```

Conclusion, Flatpak makes things a lot more annoying, so best to avoid it IMO ; ).